# Is there a way to embed an image inside a single Html (or even xml) document and have it displayed in the browser

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

I have a need to create a web based report for a custoomer, however, It must be only 1 document. Is there a way to add images so that they are not a separate file that the customer has to carry around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS word support a format called MHTML which is a single file web page [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/about-single-file-web-pages-mhtml-HP003077647.aspx)

HTML5 is suppose to support embedding images in the html file, but support for that is limited.

Comment: That is perfect exactly what I was looking for. Ideally it would also be supported by Word so the customer could edit it. Thanks a billion.

Answer (score 3):

The [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but this suffers from [limited support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages) in older versions of MSIE.

If the images are vectors, then you could use SVG or VML (depending on browser) to generate them. [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) provides a good, cross-browser way to do this with JS.